# Passing variables to get the correct message

Tags: php

I am having trouble passing two variables to get the correct statement to be displayed I can get one or the other to happen but not both so I had to comment out one of the statements for the time being.

```
 <?php   
  if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) < strtotime($today))
  <td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style="background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;"><b> Closed <?php // echo $row ['entry_cutoff_date'];?></b></a><br><br>
  if(strtotime($row['accept_entries_date']) > strtotime($today))
 {?>
  <td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style="background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;"><b>Registration opens on <?php echo $row['accept_entries_date'];?></b></a><br><br>-->


      </td> 
     <?php
     }
     else
     { ?>
         <td style='text-align: center;'><a href='event.php'><img style='width: 137px; height: 65px;' alt='' src='images/signup_button.jpg' border='0'></a><br><hr>
      </td>
     <?php
     }?>
```

Thanks in advance!

XXXX The following code was what worked with one variable and thakes me to the correct event id:

```
<?php                if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) <   strtotime($today))
        {?>
        <td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding- bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style="background:#428bca; border: 4px  solid #000; box-shadow: 1px 1px 

        3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 147px; color:#FFF;"><b>Closed</b></a><br><br>
  </td>
  <?php
  }
else
{ ?>
<td style='text-align: center;'> 

<form name="ingfrm" action="event.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="txtevent_id" id="txtevent_id" value="<?php echo   $_SESSION['event_id']; ?>" >
<input type="submit"  style='background-image:   url(images/signup_button.jpg); color: transparent; width: 143px; height: 80px;'   alt='' border='0' name="submitimage" value="signup">
</form>

<br><br>
  </td>
<?php
  }?>
```

This is what got me the correct message displayed but now the Sign Up button does not go to the correct Event ID

```
if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) < strtotime($today)){
    $tstyle = ' padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;';
    $output = "<a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border:    5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height:   65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><strong>   Closed ".$row['entry_cutoff_date']."</strong></a><br /><br />";
}elseif(strtotime($row['accept_entries_date']) > strtotime($today)){
    $tstyle = ' padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;';
    $output = "<a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border:  5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><strong>Registration opens on ".$row['accept_entries_date']."</strong></a><br /><br />";
}else{
    $tstyle = '';
    $output = "<a href='event.php'><img style='width: 137px; height: 65px;'   alt='' src='images/signup_button.jpg' border='0'></a><br /><hr />";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Mark I was trying to get that fixed but you beat me to it!

Comment: You will have to put a php close tag after the first if and open tag before the second if.

Comment: And please make sure that the php closing and opening tags are at least separated by a space from the codes.

Comment: Thanks frz3993 It now passes both but I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home4/rman/public_html/event-list-detail-view.php on line 252

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code. In your first variable you have a space between your $row and array. You also haven't properly closed or reopened your php tags. Finally your curly brackets havent been implimented properly, this is a cleaned up version of what I interpreted your desired output to be;

```
<?php   
    if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) < strtotime($today)){
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><b> Closed ".$row['entry_cutoff_date']."</b></a><br><br></td>";
    }elseif(strtotime($row['accept_entries_date']) > strtotime($today)){
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><b>Registration opens on ".$row['accept_entries_date']."</b></a><br><br></td>";
    }else{
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;'><a href='event.php'><img style='width: 137px; height: 65px;' alt='' src='images/signup_button.jpg' border='0'></a><br><hr></td>";
    }

    echo $output;

?>
```

Or

```
<?php   
    if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) < strtotime($today)){
        $tstyle = ' padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;';
        $output = "<a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><strong> Closed ".$row['entry_cutoff_date']."</strong></a><br /><br />";
    }elseif(strtotime($row['accept_entries_date']) > strtotime($today)){
        $tstyle = ' padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;';
        $output = "<a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><strong>Registration opens on ".$row['accept_entries_date']."</strong></a><br /><br />";
    }else{
        $tstyle = '';
        $output = "<a href='event.php'><img style='width: 137px; height: 65px;' alt='' src='images/signup_button.jpg' border='0'></a><br /><hr />";
    }
?>
    <td style='text-align: center;<?=$tstyle;?>'><?=$output;?></td>
```

---

Editted to users updated code:

```
<?php   
    if(strtotime($row['entry_cutoff_date']) < strtotime($today)){
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><b> Closed ".$row['entry_cutoff_date']."</b></a><br /><br /></td>";
    }elseif(strtotime($row['accept_entries_date']) > strtotime($today)){
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;  padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px;'><a href='event-list.php' style='background:#428bca; border: 5px solid #000; box-shadow: 5px 5px 3px #666666; font-size: 16px; height: 65px;line-height: 16px; padding: 15px 30px; width: 137px; color:#FFF;'><b>Registration opens on ".$row['accept_entries_date']."</b></a><br /><br /></td>";
    }else{
        $output = "<td style='text-align: center;'>
                     <form name='ingfrm' action='event.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='txtevent_id' id='txtevent_id' value='".$_SESSION['event_id']."' />
                        <input type='submit'  style='background-image: url(images/signup_button.jpg); color: transparent; width: 143px; height: 80px;' alt='' border='0' name='submitimage' value='signup' />
                     </form>
                     <br /><br />
                   </td>";
    }

    echo $output;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tarquin looks like that worked now I need some time to set up a few events to test each output . At least I have no parse error at this point and the page displayed.

Comment: Not a problem, don't forget when you are ready to accept the answer if it resolved the issue.

Comment: Found a snag and I can't seem to get the code to post properly in this reply?

Comment: What is the problem you are having, you can update your initial question (edit and place the update at the bottom as opposed to erasing your initial content)

Comment: My Signup button was an input and would go to the correct page before we made it an output. As an output it does not go to the correct page. I cant seem to post the before and after code as it wont indent in the reply.

Comment: Yeah comments dont allow great markup, edit your original question and just seperate your edit with 4 x -'s. I dont understand what you mean? Your button was an image with a href link on it in your original code it was never an 'input' per say.

Comment: The code you supplied in your original post greatly differs from that of your updated code. Simply place your form data into the output variable instead of the `<a href` tag

Comment: I cant seem to get it my file goes all the way to the </html> tag at the bottom and I get a parse error unexpected end of file. Can't figure out what the problem is. Thanks for all your help I just need to figure out how to get each Sign up button to go to the correct event id with the added code you gave me to get the correct message displayed.when there is no Signup button to dosplay..

Comment: The problem is you havent been clear in how the event ID is stored/displayed or otherwise output. If you are pulling it from the database, you can use an `events.php?id=$row['id']` and go back to using the `<a href=` instead of the form. The updated code snippet I provided gives you exactly what your code has, except with the fixes of the original answer. | There is a good chance you need to sit down and learn a bit more about PHP before continuing as most of the mistakes so far are PHP 101 (I dont mean this to be rude, just to help guide you)

Comment: Yes I am a rookie! I tried the <a href='event.php?eventid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>'>

Comment: In order for that to work, you need to rewrite your event.php file as well.

Comment: Yes I am working event.php now to get it where it needs to be. Again I really appreciate your help, you did get me what I was after and in the end I will accomplish what is needed to get that to work properly!